# Linux liveCD file-SIZES structure

Tags: live-usb, livecd

I want to create LiveCD/liveUSB iso with basic linux cli tools. No X-server at all. With both i686 and x86_64 architecture (to boot on older and newer computers). And to be as less as possible size.
After spending too much days in exploring that subject, i still do not understand, nor have a feeling what are the main parts inside iso.

Can someone explain what are the main parts inside linux liveCD functional installation and approximate sizes of main parts.

- Why archiso livecd creator, clonezilla, gparted-live cd, puppy-linux all of them have more than 220mb result iso (double this size when creating multi-architecture iso).
- Why tiny-core-linux have only 10mb???? what is kernel-size, what is main libraries size, what do you really have to put inside to just make multi-arch 'dd, nc, fdisk, ip, vi - functional" and let's say no wifi at all. Can tiny-core-linux be "doubled" fot both arch with one boot-loader, and to make ~30mb iso that conforms this needs? ... I have no time to test all of that one by one.